# Excel VBA SQL JOIN expression not supported

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to perform an easy left join. I have two tables t1 and t2. Both contain a column "ISIN". I want the ISINs from t1 joind with the column "Issuer" from t2. The code gives me an error "JOIN expression not supoorted".

```
conn.Open sconnect
    strSQL = "SELECT [t1$].[ISIN], [t2$].[ISSUER] " & _
         "FROM [t1$], [t2$] " & _
         "LEFT JOIN [t1$] ON [t1$].[ISIN] = [t2$].[ISIN]"
    mrs.Open strSQL, conn
        ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(1, 1), ws4.Cells(1, 1)).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    mrs.Close
conn.Close
```

I am a beginner in SQL and can't figure it out. I think it might have something to do with missing brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `FROM [t1$], [t2$]` with an explicit join.

Try this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [t1$].[ISIN], [t2$].[ISSUER] " & _
         "FROM [t1$] " & _
         "LEFT JOIN [t2$] ON [t1$].[ISIN] = [t2$].[ISIN]"
```

Comment: 2nd'ed. Non ansi joins are kind of a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1):

You have done wrong with the query. Do it like below :

```
conn.Open sconnect
    strSQL = "SELECT [t1$].[ISIN], [t2$].[ISSUER] " & _
         "FROM [t1$] " & _
         "LEFT JOIN [t2$] ON [t1$].[ISIN] = [t2$].[ISIN]"
    mrs.Open strSQL, conn
        ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(1, 1), ws4.Cells(1, 1)).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    mrs.Close
conn.Close
```